# Pandas groupby on comma separated values

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to calculate the count of one column grouped by comma separated values in another column.

The table looks like this:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
A,B,C   P1
A,C     P1
A,C     P2
D       P3
```

The output should look like this:

```
P1     A     2
       B     1
       C     2
P2     A     1
       C     1
P3     D     1
```

The code I have tried is like this:

```
new_df = (new_df.set_index('ColumnB')['ColumnA'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(name='ColumnA').groupby('ColumnA'))
```

Cannot figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for `Series with MultiIndex`:

```
new_df = (new_df.set_index('ColumnB')['ColumnA']
                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                .stack()).reset_index(name='ColumnA')
                .groupby(['ColumnB','ColumnA'])
                .size())

print (new_df)
ColumnB  ColumnA
P1       A          2
         B          1
         C          2
P2       A          1
         C          1
P3       D          1
dtype: int64
```